# How can I generate HTML report for gtest results (XML files)?

Tags: googletest

I tried to use **junitreport** but XML file content is not well recognized.

---

@dmeister

http://code.google.com/p/googletest/issues/detail?id=114

> [...] Google Test was designed to match our internal tools which expect the
>   XML report to match the format of those produced by the "junit" Ant
>   task, which has "testsuite" as the root element. [...]

This is what gtest (1.6.0) generates:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testsuites tests="1" failures="0" disabled="0" errors="0" time="0" name="AllTests">
    <testsuite name="SimpleTest" tests="1" failures="0" disabled="0" errors="0" time="0">
        <testcase name="Test_1" status="run" time="0" classname="SimpleTest" />
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

This is the error message returned by junitreport:

> SimpleTest.xml is not a valid testsuite XML document

Comment: Oh, it should be recognized. The gtest team is pretty serious about having the XML format compatible to junit. Can you provide a bit more information? I use it together with the junit report generation of Hudson/Jenkins and it always works great.

Answer (score 5):

I did it for myself with Python 2.*: https://github.com/burlachenkok/gtest_report

Also this gtest_report supports comparision of 2 or more google test results.
If to be honest it was the prime goal.

Answer (score 3):

The junitreport expects file with `testsuite` as root element. It than merges multiple files with a `testsuite` root element together into a single report.

You can write a small helper script to split the gtest xml files into one file per `testsuite` tag. And then feed this files into the junit report.

The jenkins junit reporting accepts also merged test files with `testsuites` as root element. So it accepts the files generated by gtest directly.

Comment: I wrote an XSLT transformation to convert <testsuites> into <testsuite>. Result is better but far from perfect: no class/package recognition and so on.